# How to append querystring to GruntBuilder on Sails?

Tags: gruntjs, npm, sails.js

My assets are 'linked' like

```
<script src="/js/library-x.js"></script>
```

And I want to use

```
<script src="/js/library-x.js?v=GITHUB_LAST_COMMIT"></script>
```

Or even:

```
<script src="/js/library-x.js?v=NPM_PACKAGE_VERSION"></script>
```

PS: At config/globals.js I have something like:

```
module.exports.globals = {
    ....
    package: require('../package.json')
};
```

The only problem is the grunt linker, that replace the string at my layout every time it lifts...